# Prerequisities to installing OpenLDAP on a clean Ubuntu 11.10 Server install

Tags: 11.10, server, openldap

I have just installed a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 Server and would like to setup an LDAP server.  Can someone please assist me to what I need to install prior to slapd and ldap-utils.  The server is a private server and does not require a domain name for the internet.

I am using phpldapadmin and can login with with cn=admin,dc=nodomain but then on the left side it says:

```
Logged in as:


        dc=example,dc=com
        This base entry does not exist.Create it?
```

I click on create and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow this guide from the ubuntu server team :

https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html